# How to remove the highlighting of the text box?

Tags: forms, magento-community, magento1.9.2.4

My magento version is 1.9.2.4. I inherited the rwd theme package and built theme from it.

When I click on any text box it is getting `highlighted` in blue color like below:

[image]

I tried removing `.input-text:focus` from `rwd` theme but it is not working for chrome.

Comment: which magento version and which edition you use?? Are you working on the default theme or custom theme??

Comment: My magento version is 1.9.2.4. I inherited the rwd theme package and built theme from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. I removed the style:

`.input-text:focus{ border: 1px solid $c-input-border-focus;}`

& just added the style :

```
.input-text:focus{outline:none;}
```

May this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the below from styles.css file.

```
.input-text:focus {
  border: 1px solid #3399cc;
}
```

Comment: hey we just have to add `outline:none;` Anyway you for your response :)